# Batch file randomizer 1-30 then output 5 Numbers

Tags: batch-file, random

I need a batch file randomizer to randomly select 5 numbers from 1-30 then output them. I have researched and found nothing that is useful to me. I am a Beginner so if you could make the code simple and explain it so i can reproduce it later if i need it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RANDOM` -- that's what you are looking for.

`RANDOM` gives a number between `0` and `32767`.

Example:

```
set /a num=%random% 
echo.%num%
```

This will output a number between `0` and `32767`.

---

But if you want to reduce that number do this:

```
set /a num=%random% %%5
echo.%num%
```

This will output a number between `0` and `4`.

---

In your case (range `1` to `30`) do this:

```
set /a num1=%random% %%30 +1
set /a num2=%random% %%30 +1
set /a num3=%random% %%30 +1
set /a num4=%random% %%30 +1
set /a num5=%random% %%30 +1

echo %num1%
echo %num2%
echo %num3%
echo %num4%
echo %num5%
```

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: with `set /a num=%random% %5` you will get output between 0 and **4**.  add one to get output between 1 and 5

Comment: :| ok thnx for telling

Comment: `%RANDOM%` will return numbers from `0` to **`32767`**!

Answer (score 3):

batch noob answer is absolutly correct, but can generate duplicated numbers. For an option with no duplicate numbers,

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    for /F "tokens=2" %%l in ('cmd /v:on /c "@for /L %%n in (1 1 30) do @echo ^!random^! %%n"^|sort^|more +25') do (
        echo %%l
    )
```

It spawns a cmd (`cmd /v:on /c "...."`) to generate a list of numbers 1-30 prefixed with a random number, this list is then sorted (`sort`), using the random number as key. Once sorted, `more +25` is used to skip the first 25 numbers in list, and then, a `for /F` is used to step over the 5 last lines, taking the second token from it (the lines contains the random number and the number from 1-30) and echoing it to console

Comment: +1, Good idea, but your script will give the exact same sequence if run multiple times within 1 second because of the [random number seed issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19694573/1012053) when CMD.EXE is launched. Better to write the list of random numbers to a file without launching new CMD.EXE, and then read the file with FOR /F.