# Batch random function giving same first output

Tags: batch-file, random, random-seed

In my batch program, I have this line in the middle of it:

```
set /a scramble=%random%
```

The problem here is that everytime I open the batch file, it gives me the same output, for example I open it and it sets %scramble% to 17534, the next time I open it, it is very similar, for example 17546, increasing by a small amount. If I loop it, then only the first random number is similar, all the rest are random.

For example The first time I run it, it gives me this list of numbers:

> 23486,32645,4854

the second time it gives

> 23498,26374,17322

So only the first is similar.

A simple workaround is to put `echo %random%` and then `cls` in the beginning of the batch, so it's not a problem for me, but I'm just wondering why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random number generator in cmd uses the current time (with second resolution) to seed the prng. This initialization is done once per `cmd` instance.

So, if you are running your batch file in a new `cmd` instance each time, the seed is very similar in each case.

But if you start your batch file several times inside the same `cmd` instance, the sequences will not be so similar as the initialization is done only once.

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19694021/2861476)

Comment: *"But if you start your batch file several times inside the same cmd instance, the sequences will not be so similar as the initialization is done only once."* - I don't understand your point, especially since you know that if several batch processes start within the same second, they each get the same "random" sequence. I interpret your sentence to mean the opposite.

Comment: @dbenham, take this `x.cmd` batch file `@echo %random%`. Now, from command line execute `for /l %a in (1 1 10) do @start /b cmd /c x.cmd` and then execute `for /l %a in (1 1 10) do @call x.cmd`. PRNG is initialized once per **`cmd` process**, not per batch file execution. The *inside the same cmd instance* makes the difference