# %RANDOM% returning same output every execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

The following script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /R %%f in (./*.avi;./*.mp4) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
ECHO %rand%
ECHO "!file[%rand%]!"
endlocal
PAUSE
```

Returns the same random number and therefore file every execution. Please could you suggest a solution with a detailed description of why the problem was occurring.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PRNG used by `cmd` is initialized using the current time, with a one second resolution, once per `cmd` instance (this behaviour was exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19694021/2861476)). Two separate `cmd` instances started in the same second will generate the same pseudo random sequence.

But sucesive executions of the same or different batch files inside the same `cmd` instance will retrieve different (or not, it is random) "random" sequences.

In the first case, with separate instances started at the same or near seconds, you can obtain the indicated behaviour exposed in your question, but the problem is increased by the arithmetics in your code.

If `n` is the same or similar for each execution, and `%random%` return a value near the one returned in the previous execution (as you describe), then `n*%random%` will return a result near to one in the previous execution. Divided by 32768 any difference will be discarded and you end with the same selected file.

In this case it is better to use the modulo operator. Being the remainder of the division, it is easier to get a different result from only slightly different starting random value

```
set /a "rand=%random% %% n + 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce this, but if the problem is related to %random% being queried with tiny intervals and it only changes in small quantities, then another formula might be a solution. With the following alternative you get a different output even if %random% only changes with 1:

```
set /A "rand=(%random% %% n)+1"
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this syntax answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Indeed, that was too short. I've edited my answer. Thank you.